# Reliable Mastercard ATMs in Antigua?

Tags: money, payment-cards, guatemala

I lost my Visa debit card and I have to use my Mastercard Credit card in Guatemala. Where I am currently, Flores, there are no ATMs or banks that accept Mastercard.

I will be in Antigua by tonight however, and need the location of an ATM or financial institution where I can reliably access money.

I've tried to use Mastercard's ATM locator but one it directed me to didn't work, even though it said on the outside that it did. I've also tried calling them but I repeatedly got lost in their voice command system.

One helpful Guatemalan (that said, they have all been helpful) seemed to indicate that Mastercard doesn't work in Guatemala outside the international airports. That said, my Spanish is very basic as was his English so I can't be certain.

Could responders indicate whether there are ATMs that reliably take Mastercard credit cards in Antigua or if you could confirm whether it's true that only the international airports have ATMs that accept Mastercard in Guatemala?

Note: I had used my Mastercard to access money through an ATM in Mexico and my bank has confirmed that there isn't a block on my account.

It would be greatly appreciated! Very much running out of money.

Thanks.

Comment: Author update: I've reached Antigua and found an ATM that works with my MasterCard Credit Card. It's inside the Citibank in the north west corner of the main park in Antigua. Several other ATMs that were not located in banks didn't work so it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Write that up as an answer to help anyone else looking for it, as they might miss it in a comment. :)  Doubly so since it appears none of the rest of us have recent knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

Author updated the post with:

> I've reached Antigua and found an ATM that works with my MasterCard Credit Card. It's inside the Citibank in the north west corner of the main park in Antigua. Several other ATMs that were not located in banks didn't work so it's something to be aware of.

According to the [Citibank Guatemala website](https://www.citibank.com.gt/puntosContacto/agencias.htm) this particular branch is located at:

```
4a. Avenida y 4ª Calle esquina No. 2, Antigua, Guatemala
```

[Approximate location on Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/5o6gM):

[image]]